# Can you play with your personal drones in DRONE The Game?

Tags: drone-the-game

I have seen in videos that D.R.O.N.E. The Game that you were not able to actually compete with your own created drones, because the developers had not made it available yet.  Have they made it so you can compete with your own created drones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but only in online test/practice mode.

You cannot assign custom drones to your garage slots, so you cannot use them in ranked matchmaking.

Here are the steps to access online PVP with custom drones:

1. From the main menu, select "Drone Editor" and acknowledge the disclaimer.
2. In the top right corner, click the hamburger menu, then Load Drone, then select the drone blueprint you want to load:

[image]

3. Now click "Test Flight" in the lower right corner:

[image]

4. Select "Test Flight Online" in the upper left corner and acknowledge the disclaimer:

[image]

You will be placed in an online PVP match with your custom drone.

Comment: But you can fight in the test/practice mode, right?  I thought that's what I had seen, anyway

Comment: @RBlong2us Yes, it is online PVP, but unranked, and everyone else is testing their drones too, so its only usefulness is for practice and/or testing. It's "playing online", but not "PLAYING ONLINE" if that makes any sense lol

Comment: well at least you can shoot each other!

Comment: I actually tried this mode out, and there were only bots.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Then you did it wrong... I'll update the answer with steps and screenshots

Comment: Thanks!  Nice job on your post!